# How do I make the search text input appear left only if it's an entered term?

Tags: jquery, asp-classic

Using the code below I can show a default text message in the input box that shows by default the value in the textbox and removes it when clicked.  After that the text goes to the left, which is what I need.  Now when the user enters a search term and hits search it takes them to a results page.  The search box still shows on the top on the results page but now instead of text being centered I need the text shown on the left if it's ONLY a search term not the default search placeholder.  How can I do this? JQuery maybe?

I am using ASP and here's the input box:

```
<input id="search_input" type="text" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return 
inputSBox_onkeypress(event, this);" onkeyup="return inputSBox_onkeyup(event,this);"
onfocus="inputSBox_onfocus(this);" onblur="inputSBox_onblur(this);" searchtype="
<%=(int)SearchType%>" value="<%=GetboxValue() %>"class="menu">
```

CSS:

```
#search_input {
width: 337px;
height: 36px;
margin-left: 7px;
font-style: italic;
padding-left: 4px;
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
-ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
-o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
outline: medium none;
padding: 0;
margin: -10px 1px 3px 0px;
border: 1px solid #DADADA;
box-shadow:inset 0 0 4px 0 #dfdfdf;
-moz-box-shadow:inset 0 0 4px 0 #dfdfdf;
-wevkit-box-shadow:inset 0 0 4px 0 #dfdfdf;
text-align: center;
font-size: 16px;
color: #9A9A9A;
font-family: Georgia, Arial, sans-serif;
}

#search_imput:focus {
border: 1px solid rgba(81, 203, 238, 1);
color: #797f86;
text-align: left;
width: 327px;
padding-left: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Can't you just use Request.Querystring or Request.Form?

Answer (score 1):

You could use jQuery to set text-align to left if the input value is not empty, like this:

```
$(function() {
    if ($("#search_input").val() != "")
        $("#search_input").css("text-align", "left");
});
```

However, if the user clears the input value then the content will still be aligned left.

A better solution would be to use jQuery to apply a different class when there is a value. You could tap into your existing JavaScript functions for focus and blur.

Comment: Thanks! I tried using it but it makes the text go to the left.  Even the placeholder.  I need the placeholder to always be centered but if there is user inputted text then it should only be on the left.

Comment: Can you post your inputSBox_onfocus inputSBox_onblur functions as they are probably going to have to be changed?